# How to read specified amount of files in directory in python?

Tags: file, python-3.x, hdf5

I am using python3.
I have a folder with 1000 binary files. Now, I am reading all the files in the directory one by one:

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.bin')):
    with open(filename, "rb") as pathSig:
```

I do some stuff on it and save it to hdf5 file. As this process is using too much memory, I would like to read first 100 files one by one save it to hdf5 then read another 100 files save it and so on. Is there any elegant way how to do it in python?

Comment: Why do you think reading 100 files at a time would use less memory than reading 1 at a time ? I'm pretty sure it will have the opposite effect.

Comment: I do not want to read 100 files at once. I want to read files one by one but  not all files in directory, just specified amount of them. I want to save the product to hdf5 and then process another 100 files one by one and append it to the existing hdf5.